# Cannot make WebSockets working in Payara 5.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, cdi, payara

I was trying to make the old Java 7 EE WebSocket application of: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html work in Payara Server 5.184 #badassfish (build 89)

However, the WebSocket (@ServerEndpoint) fails to be instantiated.

```
Severe:   Exception in thread "glassfish-web-async-thread-1"  Severe: 
java.lang.NullPointerException  at
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl.processAllDataRead(InputBuffer.java:492) at
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl.access$800(InputBuffer.java:385) at
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl$2.run(InputBuffer.java:475) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

By enabling CDI development mode I see:

```
WARN:   WELD-001703: Unable to determine the @Intercepted Bean<?> for
[UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Intercepted private
 org.jboss.weld.probe.InvocationMonitor.interceptedBean WARN:  
PROBE-000020: A problem occured during monitoring of bean instance
construction: null java.lang.RuntimeException: at
com.magicpigeon.websocket.DeviceWebSocketServer.<init>(DeviceWebSocketServer.java:1) at
com.magicpigeon.websocket.DeviceWebSocketServer$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.<init>(Unknown Source) at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

`DeviceWebSocketServer` is my @ServerEndpoint class.
Is there any bug related to CDI? What can I be missing?.

Code is here: https://github.com/DanielMerchan/WebsocketHome if someone wants to give it a try. This was working in the past in my old Netbeans with Glassfish (do not remember the version).

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure those two are related. The former is a NPE. The latter are warnings from what you call a "CDI development mode" but what is in fact a [Weld's Probe tool](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#devmode). Thing is, Probe isn't used by default and only kicks in once you start up in Weld development mode. Hence it shouldn't cause the first error.

Comment: Thanks. As you mentioned, are not related, but I am surprise a example which worked perfectly in earlier versions of Glassfish and WebLogic now does not work in Payara and TomEE.

Answer (score 0):

It works if I keep Java EE 7. 
Do not know what is happening when upgraded to Java EE 8.